# Angular - keep values of variables even after navigating away

Tags: angular, angular5

On my first Home Component, on ngOnInit I call a function that subscribes results to a variable and displays those results :

```
  ngOnInit() {
       this.dataService.getAllData().subscribe(results =>
             this.userData = results.userData;
   }
```

On my HTML I have a function where I need to remove some elements from the array :

```
      this.userData.splice(this.removedIndex, 1)
```

When navigating away from that screen, and coming back, because of ngOnInit, the userData will have ALL the data from the service again and I need to have only the data remaining after the splice.
Once logging out and logging back in, then all data can be displayed.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Store this information in a service rather than the component and give your service the appropriate lifecycle.

Comment: Use a separate service or local storage, session storage to store your data.. Don't try to keep data in a component.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the data on a service, not locally. It can be something as simple as:

```
class DataHoldingService {
  data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([1, 2, 3, 4]);
  // or get from, say, backend:
  constructor() {
    this.backend.getData().subscribe(data => this.data$.next(data));
  }
}
```

Then your component gets this on init:

```
class MyComponent {
  myData: any[];
  constructor(private dataService: MyDataService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }

  // when removing that index:
  removeData(index: number) {
    this.data.splice(index, 1);
    this.dataService.next(this.data);
  }
}
```

This way, when your component removes the index, you'll have the updated data on the service as well as locally.

To survive full page reloads, you need a bit more. Here's a naive example:

```
class DataHoldingService {
  data$: new Observable<any[]>;
  private dataObserver: Observer;
  constructor() {
    this.data$ = new Observable(observer => {
      this.dataObserver = observer;
      this.loadInitialData();
    });
  }

  setData(data) {
   localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
   this.dataObserver.next(data);
  }

  loadInitialData() {
    let data = [];
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    } catch (e) {
      /* no data */
    }
    this.dataObserver.next(data);
}
```

Of course, now your component can't call `next()` but has to use `setData()`:

```
class MyComponent {
  // other stuff is the same

  // removing that item, or adding or whatever
  removeItem(index: number) {
    this.data.splice(index, 1);
    this.dataService.setData(data);
  }
}
```

Now your data service will always keep a copy of the data in localStorage. So even if you refresh the page, you still get the edited data. You still need to manage the lifecycle of it all (load data from backend, you may need to conditionally do that initial load, cleanup on login/logout etc).

Comment: Thank you!!!
but after I added the condition if it is on localStorage then call loadInitialData else call my .subscribe function,
What do I assign to this.observableData then ?
So that on the component I get that data?

Comment: Well, that is on you to decide (or I didn't understand the question). Your service has that Observable and you want to set some initial value. You can probably simply set an empty array to start with. Then later on, you can decide whether to load from backend or from localStorage or whatever, and simply call `observer.next(new Data)`. But what is the correct flow, I think you need to decide that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can HTML5 localstorage to keep the data -- retrieve data after you closed the browser,

2.create a service and inject in your app.module.ts So that all your components share the same instance of the service